# Search a list for a string and store it in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a list of strings generated from a text file and I need to test an input string to see if it has any of the words in my list. I then need to store the matching string/strings so that they can be used later. Currently I am using

```
has_words = any(string in op_text for string in words)
```

but I believe this only returns true/false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a list of matching words instead, using a list comprehension:

```
matching = [string for string in words if string in op_text]
```

Comment: ok, a followup question. I have my words being imported from a text file where each line is a separate string that I am interested in searching for. 

    `words = open(fileName, 'database.doc')`

Will this matching have each index be a line in the document even if the line has spaces (ie multiple words in the line)?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what *so that they can be used later* means, you can use a set...

```
op_words = {'one', 'bob', 'whatever'}
matching = op_words.intersection(words)
```